# Upgrade of Dell Latitude USB port

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, upgrade, port

Received Dell Latitude C400 without wireless capability. Tried usb 2.0 adapter to access wifi but got "need hi-speed USB controller to use 2.0 USB adapter". Do I need software or hardware to resolve this?  Clueless in MD?

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop only has USB 1.1 ports; this is a hardware limitation and the built-in ports are not upgradeable (just like you can't convert a USB2 port into a USB3 port on any other PC).

Instead, laptops of this era usually have a **CardBus**/PC-Card slot for inserting various expansion cards. CardBus is PCI and offers decent performance (easily up to 100 Mbps) and you can still find Wi-Fi 802.11n CardBus adapters on eBay. There also are cards providing USB 2.0 ports.

(Note: These products are often mislabeled as **"PCMCIA"** cards, so you'll need to search for both "`cardbus 802.11`" and "`pcmcia 802.11`" to find all results. If the connector has a gold-coloured shield with dimples, it's the newer CardBus. If it's plain gray, it's the old and slow PCMCIA/PC-Card.)

Comment: the C400 did use CardBus

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to purchase the internal WiFi card from Dell.  It is called the Dell True Mobile 1150 Series Mini-PCI Card.  That is a *really* old laptop and they might not carry parts for it anymore.

If they dont have it, you might be able to find one elsewhere.

Even if you do find one and install it, it will not be as fast as modern wireless devices, as it used an older standard.

Comment: Can you install a third-party Mini-PCI card instead, or is Dell one of those companies which refuse to allow that?

Comment: @grawity I honestly dont know.  I would assume Dell just rebranded an Intel or Broadcom card, so one of those might work.